# globally translate 'back' text in iOS navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift

in iOS NavigationController when ever previous ViewController does not have a title / or current page title is tool large, the back button is labeled with "back".

How can I translate this 'back' for other locals.
I know that there is another option to use `lastViewController.navigationItem?.backBarButtonItem?.title` but it changes the back button completely. I just what to change the 'back' text whenever complete title does not fit in.

Comment: Do you want to translate it to another language or change it to a different English word?

Comment: I want to translate it for other locals

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. Usually you shouldn't present the app's UI in a language different from the device language. Using `NSLocalizedString` will give you the desired behavior for free for your own UI strings.

And "Back" will automatically be "Zurück" when the device's language is changed to German, for example.

When the user has set his/her iOS device to Spanish, your app should be in Spanish. When it's set to English, the app should be in English. You should not present your app in Spanish unless the user has set his/her device language to Spanish.

Comment: Yes you're right but lots of languages are not supported by Apple to be chosen as device language like 'Persian'

Comment: Ah, OK. You can set Persian as a Preferred Language: https://github.com/jfahrenkrug/xcode-languages/blob/master/xcode-languages.json#L2135 but it won't switch the whole iPhone UI to Persian. It will enable you to use NSLocalizedString though. But you're right: You might still have to manually deal with non-localized Apple UI strings.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that looks for the title string size and changes the back button from a “Back” string (relative to local language) to a back arrow if the title string size exceeds a certain amount of characters. Or save yourself some time and just keep the back button as a back arrow all of the time. Everyone knows a “<“ means go back when presented in a navigation bar.